# Separate containers vs One container - Unity

Tags: .net, unity-container, ioc-container, containers

Currently my team is working on a project which uses a "process" model. Each process is composed of "steps" these steps can be each "IValidationStep" or "ITransactionStep". In each case the logic is different (Transaction steps can Rollback).

These steps will be resolved via Unity.

In our project we are going to build general validation and transaction logic using steps which can be replace in Unity configuration.

We are currently debating whether to separate the containers (container per flow which consists of validation processes and transaction processes) or to just keep it all in one container.

I would like to get your honest opinions on separating containers vs one container. Keep in mind that our project should be completely testable via unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code must be completely testable your processes will probably get all dependencies (steps) via dependency injection. In such case process will be completely independent on Unity and will not hold any reference to `UnityContainer`. The only code which will have reference to `UnityContainer` will be the logic instancing and executing your processes. This leads me to single `UnityContainer` with named types registrations.

Comment: This was one of our considerations, as separating the containers means that BL code must get a specific unity container via configuration section. Hence the code will reference UnityContainer.

Comment: It will make your code dependent on concrete unity configuration which is bad. All your unit tests will have to use unity to correctly configure tested process.

Comment: True, as I see it, it seems that in separating UnityContainers we will need to hold a Unity.Config in our testing environment.

So when is it preferable to separate UnityContainers?

Comment: I completely agree with Ladislav. You can find more information on why this is bad here: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

why not starting with one container and refactor to multiple when needed, sometime you just have to start and see where you end to know the right approach...

Comment: I believe that you are correct but another issue is that we are currently writing other framework component to be used in this project and others.
An example is a NotificationManager to send notifications (email, sms, etc.). The NotificationManager uses a INotificationProvider which will be registered in UnityContainer. Since it is framework code we need to know whether to get the INotificationProvider via dependancy injection or via getting a specific UnityContainer via UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration